# How do Aweber and FeedBlitz report subscriber numbers to Feedburner?

Tags: parsing, feed, syndication-feed

I've looked all over for some documentation on this, but haven't found it.  Some posts reference a user-agent string:

http://groups.google.com/group/feedburner-services/browse_thread/thread/7aee14cf6a2432e7/49464335d2228e25?lnk=gst&q=aweber#49464335d2228e25

I had assumed there would be an API or something.  More generally, how does ANY rss feed reader/aggregator (like Bloglines, etc) report subscriber numbers to Feedburner?

I'm working on developing a new app that would need this functionality.

Thanks for your help!
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered in your link, you put the subscriber count in your user-agent, then you contact the [Feedburner Support Group](http://groups.google.com/group/feedburner) and tell them what format you will be using.

The consensus format is something

```
User-agent: Service Name (http://example.com/service/info/; ### subscribers ; [optional feed identifier] )
```

The optional feed identifier is typically used if you run several different services, and fetch the feed separately for each one; e.g. if you have a mail service and a web-based reader service, with different subscribers, then you might either use:

```
User-agent: SO Agg/1.3 (http://example.com/SOAgg ; 5000 subscribers ; feed-id=mail-134 )
```

on request for the mailer, and

```
User-agent: SO Agg/1.3 (http://example.com/SOAgg ; 2000 subscribers ; feed-id=web-134 )
```

on the request for the website; or use

```
User-agent: SO Agg/1.3 (http://example.com/SOAgg ; 7000 subscribers ;  )
```

if your system makes only one request for both services...

You will usually need to specify what IP addresses are authorised to request the feed with that user-agent, as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response!  To clarify, what url is feedburner polling to get back this info?  Feedburner has to pass you the rss feed in question as a parameter somehow right?  When specifying IP addresses, only the feedburner IP's should be allowed to poll it right?  Or am i missing something.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok I realized I was thinking about it backwards.  Feedburner isn't polling you to get subscriber count, you are polling feedburner to get the feed, and in the process you pass along how many people you're sending it to.  Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Many major aggregators report user stats by including them as part of the useragent string. Examples:

- [Bloglines reporting description in blog comment](http://www.intertwingly.net/blog/1716.html#c1077175023)
- [Google Reader: Tips for Publishers](http://www.google.com/help/reader/publishers.html#faq)
- [PostRank: Reporting Subscription Counts](http://blog.postrank.com/2007/09/24/aiderss-reporting-subscribtion-counts/)

There's no standard for this at this time.

To the best of my knowledge, folks will contact major feed analytics vendors like [Feedburner](http://www.feedburner.com/) directly, to make sure their useragent-based reporting is being counted.

Comment: Ok good info, thanks!  Question: What URL is Feedburner polling to get back this user-agent?  Feedburner has to pass you the rss feed in question somehow as well, right?  Thanks for your help...I know some of this is probably obvious, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok I realized I was thinking about it backwards.  Feedburner isn't polling you to get subscriber count, you are polling feedburner to get the feed, and in the process you pass along how many people you're sending it to.  Makes more sense now.